# TinkerCAD schematic to Eagle for PCB design

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad, pcb-fabrication, arduino-uno

I am new to the world of PCB design but I am having a hard time trying to convert my .brd file from TinkerCAD to Eagle. I've been following this tutorial for my conversion needs but it's almost impossible with the error I have been getting [Link to tutorial](https://www.buildcircuit.com/transform-your-tinkercad-arduino-projects-into-pcb-in-5-steps/).

Here is a picture of the error. [image].
I tried expanding the board area but nothing seems to stick and I keep getting the warning message. I also try to stick to the positive XY coordinates but that has been useless as well. Any tips on getting this design to work? Here is a picture [image: TinkerCAD image of the PCB design I am trying to create]

Comment: The free version of Eagle has a size limitation of 80 sq cm, if your board is larger than this, you'll get that error. It may also only have 2 layers.

Comment: You're right, The Uno does not fit within those limitations and I had to get the premium version.